# Recover disk space after uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: hard-drive, virtualization, disk-space, virtualbox

I uninstalled Virtualbox from my MacBook with Big Sur, and deleted the virtual disk image it used. That was a 40G file, easily 4% of the whole drive. And it wasn't sparse; I often run out of disk space in the VM. But when I look with "df" in a terminal, there is hardly any change. Why?

Yes, I have emptied the trash. And I have rebooted.

Could this have something to do with TimeMachine? The whole directory including the disk image was excluded from TimeMachine at this point. But maybe it wasn't always.

Comment: It sounds a bit (a good size bit) like #102628.

Comment: Ok, now I am *really* confused. Today, about 10 days after the original event, and after I posted my question,  the space has re-appeared! I don't have much of an idea why/how. I have only 2 remote guesses: (A) I think this was the first time thereafter that I left my Mac on and sleeping overnight; generally I turn it off completely. I know that cronjobs and launcher tasks don't run when I turn it off, but I wouldn't expect reclaiming space from deleted files would be done in such way?? (B) Today I removed the time machine drive I was using when that VM was created.